# How to insert a background image that fits completely in HTML Service of Google App Script?

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

Ok. So I use HTMLService to create the UI in Google App Script. In all ways when I tried to have a background image or color, it doesnot fit the entire  webpage.Further it gets extended as I add contents dynamically to the body and goes off if I delete it.The same applies to the background color.

Somebody help me to load a color/image for the entire page.

Google Script Code:

```
function doGet(){
var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("source");
html.setTitle("Technology Tagger");
return html;
}
```

css:

```
body{
background-color:#B7CEEC;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw your code, please fix the following:

1. Remove the `<center>` tags completely. It is not good.
2. Add the CSS Background for the `body` to cover the whole thing.

   ```
   body {background-color: #b7ceec;}
   ```
3. Give the following styles to make it alright:

   ```
   * {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; overflow: hidden;}
   h1, h2, h3, p {margin: 0 0 10px;}
   ```
4. Please, for god sake, don't use `font-family: Comic Sans MS`, instead go for `Segoe UI`.

Comment: Woah... After a week? Okay, show your generated HTML and CSS.

Comment: @KavithaMadhavaraj Please add this: `html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}`

Comment: @KavithaMadhavaraj Is there a live URL that we can see?

Comment: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzoXPObamfTXqy44jUihq8Oi8NoM901fEhAgnY-65fwO_uqeJPj/exec

Comment: @KavithaMadhavaraj Check now!

Comment: So, What does the <center> tag got to do with background image.? I'm just being curious. Further, I want everything to be aligned center. Then the css is same as you mentioned in my code. And the font-family I have used is 'Brush Script MT' not the one you mentioned. And the styles make the blue color appear right from the beginning. But it dint cover the entire page still.